# Reducing CPU Utilization

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, cpu-usage

I am using python3.3, for reading a directory that has 10 files each of 20Mb, I am using thread pool executor with max of 10 threads and submitting the files to be read. I am reading a chunk of 1Mb at a time and then storing each lines from all the files to a thread safe list. When I look at the top command the cpu utilization is pretty high approx. 100% above any suggestion to reduce the cpu utilization. Below is the snippet.

```
all_lines_list = []
while True:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for each_file in file_list:
            executor.submit(trigger, each_file)
def trigger(filename):
    with open(filename, "r")as fp:
        buff = fp.read(1000000)
        buff_lines = buff.split('\n')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    for each_line in buff_lines:
        all_lines_list.append(each_line)
```

Comment: "any suggestion to reduce the cpu utilization" - yeah, spawn less threads!

Comment: actually, there may be more than 100 files in a directory too so 10 threads are needed for some speedy process.

Comment: Why is title to your question "Increasing CPU utilization" when your question is about "reducing the cpu utilization"?

Comment: changes done @selbie

Comment: Actually I stated the problem caused as heading @selbie

Comment: You've created ten threads whole sole purpose is to fight over the same I/O resource and the same list. Why?!

Comment: Did you try something like `lines = input.readlines()` it might be optimized already.

Comment: no each thread will take different files to be read as input, list is same because if the list size grows more than 20 Mb are so I will compress and store it to a file @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @ArunagiriswaranEzhilan It doesn't matter that they're reading different files, they're not reading from 10 different devices, so they're still fighting over the same I/O. There's no point in creating lots of threads if they all need precisely the same resources at precisely the same time -- they'll just slow each other down.

Comment: if i use input.readlines() say for example if there is a possible hack like a single line is more than 1Gb assume, my ram is 1Gb then there is possiblity of a server crash so to avoid that situation I am reading chunk by chunk. @Marichyasana

Comment: yes, you are right but to speed things up I need to use threads @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @ArunagiriswaranEzhilan Sorry, that won't make disk I/O any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the list `extend` method, instead of repeating 1 million appends:

```
all_lines_list.extend(buff_lines)
```

instead of

```
for each_line in buff_lines:
    all_lines_list.append(each_line)
```

If that does not reduce your workload: you are putting your computer to work - 10 x times reading data and storing in memory - and you need the work done - so why the worry it is taking all the processing of one core? If you reduce it to 20% you will get your work done in 5x the time.

You have another problem there in that you are opening the files as  **text** files in Python3 and reading an specific number of characters - that might as well use some CPU as the internals might need to decode each byte to find character boundaries and line separators..
So, if your file is not using a variable-lenght text encoding, like utf-8, it might be worth to open your files in binary-mode, and decode them afterwards (and it even might be worth it to put some strategy in place to deal with variable length characters and make the reading as binary files anyway)

Of course, you could also gain advantages there in using multi-processing instead of Threading - in that way your program would use more than one CPU core to work on the Data. However, python does not have a native multiprocess shared list object - you would need to create your own data structure (and keep it safe with locks) using `multiprocess.Value` and `multiprocess.Array` objects.  Since you don't have much to process on this data but for adding it to the list, I don't think it is worth the effort.

Answer (score -1):

Each thread uses CPU time to do its share of processing.  To reduce the CPU utilization, use fewer threads.